# Kotli n 1.5.0 project upgrade

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Upgrading project to Kotlin 1.5.0 in Idea gives the following output using Build embedded in the IDE:

```
Build file '../../build.gradle.kts' line: 11

Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.5.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
    maven(url = "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx")
    maven(url = "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
}
```

However the gradle build works fine (standalone from the CLI), therefore i m  missing sthg in Intellij ?

Comment: `jcenter()` is deprecated in Gradle 7.x (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#jcenter_deprecation). Consider removing this line.

Comment: Also, problems with IDEA are frequenlty fixed with File->Invalidate Caches...